# Aborting undo command in an undo stack

Tags: c++, qt

I'm calling an [undo command](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundo.html) from within QML:

```
cppClass.undoHandler.createCommand(option)
```

The C++ undo-handler pushes undo command into undo stack:

```cpp
void UndoHandler::createCommand(
        const QString & option
        )
{
    m_undoStack->push(new Command(
                          option
                          ));
}
```

The actual C++ undo command is:

```cpp
class Command : public QUndoCommand
{
    // ...
    
    virtual void undo();
    virtual void redo();

    // ...

    Logic *m_logic;
}
```

```cpp
void Command::redo()
{
    m_outputName = m_logic->run(m_option);
}
```

And the logic runs like this:

```cpp
QString Logic::run(const QString option)
{
    if ( /*  some condition here */ ) {
        
        // ** What I want to achieve:
        // If this condition is met
        // abort the current undo-command
        // I mean pop the current undo-command which is already pushed into stack
        
    }
}
```

How can I abort/pop/break the undo-command by the above condition inside the logic? I'm not sure how it should be designed, any idea?

Comment: Do you want to undo the command or keep the result but remove the possibility to undo it?

Comment: @rubenvb I posted an answer with the approach which worked.

Comment: To be completely honest, that looks like a very convoluted and unclear solution to a as of yet unclearly described problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `if` condition before pushing undo command into stack like this:

```cpp
void UndoHandler::createCommand(
        const QString & option
        )
{
    Command *command = new Command(option);

    // Check validity before pushing undo command into undo stack
    bool isValid = command->doubleCheck();

    if (isValid) {
        m_undoStack->push(command);
    } else {
        delete command;
    }
}
```

Undo command has a new method to check the `if` condition:

```cpp
class Command : public QUndoCommand
{
    // ...
    
    virtual void undo();
    virtual void redo();

    // ...

    // New method to check validity
    bool doubleCheck();

    // ...

    Logic *m_logic;
    const QString m_option;
}

bool Command::doubleCheck() {
    return m_logic->doubleCheck(m_option);
}

void Command::redo()
{
    // Redo method has to be modified accordingly
}
```

The `if` condition is inside a separate method in logic:

```cpp
bool Logic::doubleCheck(const QString option)
{
    if ( /* some condition here */ )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QUndoCommand::setObsolete()` and make the command obsolete.

> The boolean is used for the automatic removal of commands that are not necessary in the stack anymore. The isObsolete function is checked in the functions QUndoStack::push(), QUndoStack::undo(), QUndoStack::redo(), and QUndoStack::setIndex().